# Creating Firestore missing index through an error log url doesn't work of multiple accounts

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was following this [codelab on firestore](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android). On [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-android/#5) page it introduced the option to automatically generate the Composite Index key through a link printed on Logcat.

But when I click the link, it says the project doesn't exist. Later I found out that my firebase console was logged in as secondary account (Means, I've to access firebase console like this https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/). That's why the link is not working I guess.

I tried to manipulate the link following my console url, but no luck. I also followed the official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=1#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) on this regard, but no luck, they doesn't mention the scenario about multiple accounts.

How can I manipulate this link so that it creates the indexes automatically for me, considering my situation?

Comment: Hmm... that sounds like you might be hitting a bug. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. In the meantime, you can manually create the index with the correct fields and sort orders.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the tip. I'm a fan of the whole firebase team. I'll contact them soon. I actually didn't have proper understanding of indexes when I posted, then I followed the docs and created indexes manually. but still, it's a problem worth solving